# Rock scroll or Metal Scroll clone for VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, add-on

Can anyone recommend a Visual Studio 2015 addon that mimics the awesomeness that is RockScroll/MetalScroll/RockMargin?

It looks like the amazing awesome person that made RockMargin hasn't looked at it for a couple years.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1b0d7360-40dd-447e-8bef-90e2cf52f683/view/Reviews/2

Basically if you double click a word it highlights all words that match it.  And it shows a mini-map of your code in place of the scroll bar.

Comment: I don't use RockMargin, and whenever I highlight a word all others in the page are selected in the editor and the scroll margin. I've got Productivity Power Tools and VSCommands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is [RockMargin2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2989ec7d-ca78-4041-803b-f0b5c560161b) extension with VS 2015 support.

Comment: you rock. but not marginally.

Answer (score 7):

It's built in! :)  (I literally just found out)

```
VS 2015 
-> Tools 
  -> Options 
    -> Text Editor 
      -> All Languages 
        -> Scroll Bars 
          -> Behaviour

"Use map mode for vertical scroll bar"
```

Comment: Thank you; been using this feature for a while, but on a new machine was unable to find where this option was.

Comment: More or less... It's missing features, one basic for me is to show me the matched words or find text. Such a bummer

Comment: This also works on VS 2017, at least on the Enterprise edition.

Comment: @Carles Alcolea the extension you want for VS2017 to show matched words in the margin is Match Margin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MatchMargin